# Linux terminal: Run command when changing directory

Tags: linux, shell, directory, command

I work in a Linux environment where certain modules need to be loaded for different work areas. These are separated by individual filesystem directories.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to run different 1 line commands when entering directories. I am flexible with the type of shell being used, but am currently using C Shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using bash, I would recommend you to create a function like this:

```
function custom_cd() { custom_command $1; cd $1; }
alias cd='custom_cd'
```

Here your custom command can be anything that will execute specific commands according to the directory you enter.

The alias declared afterwards makes sure that typing 'cd' will invoke the function and the real cd command.

**edit**: An example for your need

```
function custom_cd() {
    if [ -z "$1" ];
    then
        target=~
    else
        target=$1
    fi
    target=${target%/}
    parent=$(dirname `readlink -f $target`)
    grand_parent=`dirname $parent`
    script=$grand_parent/`basename $target`.sh
    if [ -x $script ];
    then
      `$script`
    fi
    cd $1
}
```

Explanation:

We create a variable containing the parent of the directory you want to enter.
Then we retrieve the parent's parent.
Then we create the script name in the grandparent directory.

Then the executability of this filename is checked, if so, the script is executed, and finally the real cd command is executed.

Be careful to define the function before the alias, else it will cause an infinite recursion !

Comment: For safety, in the function use `builtin cd` to ensure you're not hitting the alias. In fact, if you use the "builtin" command, you don't need the alias, you can name the function "cd".

Comment: @glennjackman didn't know about builtin, I suspected something like this existed, nice !

Comment: This worked great. I implemented something in this style ported over to C shell but will be making a Bash version as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could make a function to run those special commands.

```
run_command() {
  case `pwd` in
    "/path/to/dir1" )
      ...
      ;;
    "/path/to/dir2" )
      ...
      ;;
    ...
  esac
}
```

Then you call that function along with `cd` with another function for example.

```
cd2() {
  cd $1
  run_command
}

cd2 /path/to/somewhere
```

Answer (score 2):

a pretty vague question, but I think the `alias` command might help you:

```
alias cd='echo "hello $1"'
```

this will display `hello <arg given to cd>` when you try to cd somewhere

Comment: I guess it was fairly vague. I need to run a different command for a small subset of the entire filesystem. 

For example, if I want to enter directory /home/user/a then I want to run /home/a.csh.
Then, if I enter /home/scripts/b I would run /home/b.csh

Comment: What I gave you is a starter. It won't work for example if you use gnome, or some other file manager. I am not aware of some triggers that can be custom executed when you change a directory. Maybe you could hook into something related to security policies